# How to not include the query in sqlcmd output file

Tags: sqlcmd

I have a batch script that I am using to generate a dataset from a stored procedure but it keeps including the query that calls the stored procedure in the output file and I need it to stop.

The batch script is this

```
@echo off 
sqlcmd -d Database -S .\SQLExpress -I -e -q SPROC_WithData -h-1  -W -o "C:\support\test.txt"
```

The test.txt file is generated with the correct data but the first line includes the `SPROC_WithData` and I cannot figure out why. I have not had this issue with other batch scripts that generate data with a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-e` switch of `sqlcmd` means echo input. Try removing it if you don't want it echoed.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

Comment: Yikes, I am not sure how I didn't catch that i was doing -e instead of -E. Thank you very much! Not a fan of case sensitive switches